# How to store List<List<Color>> element with sharedPreferences Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to store Color list in a list, and then i want to save to local.

MylistHere:

```
  final List<List<Color>> predefinedGradients = [
    [Color(0xFFFF5F4A), Color(0xFF7A4BFF)],
    [Color(0xFFFFCB00), Color(0xFF01EA85)],
    [Color(0xFFFFCB00), Color(0xFFFF5F4A)],
    [Color(0xFF00E0E4), Color(0xFF7A4BFF)],
    [Color(0xFFFFCB00), Color(0xFF7A4BFF)],
    [Color(0xFF00E0E4), Color(0xFF01EA85)],
    [Color(0xFF3A3A62), Color(0xFF7A4BFF)]
  ];
```

Here my save function code

```
   final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   prefs.setString('SS_BRANDCOLOR_LIST_1', jsonEncode(predefinedGradients));
```

It gives me an error, when I add to 'toString()'. It's being saved, but I'm having trouble reading it because it's a string this time.

How can I store such a list, how can I use it again. I would be glad if you help.

Answer (score 0):

First convert it with:

```
jsonEncode(listName.toString());
```

then after reading from sharedPreferences, convert it again with:

```
json.decode(readString)
```

to get your list

Comment: @thekavak was it what you looking for?